# assign response html to variable and then assigning specific part of html to scope

Tags: jquery, angularjs

Im getting a json object which is a whole html page, and I would like to assign part of it (from a specific html tag, like 'article' and everything inside ONLY article) and asssign it to $scope and show it on the view.

I am making a call to an api and im working in an angularjs application. 
Below is how the function looks like and what I have tried so far:

```
controller: /*@ngInject*/["$scope", "logger", function ($scope, logger) {
    var promise = myService.getTheData();
    promise.then(success, fail);

    function success(response) {
        var data = JSON.parse(response.data);
        //console.log(data.content);

        var $div = $(data.content);
        console.log($div);
        var test = $('div.article-head', $div);
        console.log(test);

        $scope.to.testText = test;
    }

    function fail(error) {
        logger.error('there is an error', error);
    }
}]
```

data.content looks good. Its the whole html page that I requested. But neither of the assignments work... 
this is how the view looks like:

```
<div class="alert alert-success">
{{to.testText}}</div>
```

this is what the output looks like:
[image]

and this is what the console looks like:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Create a directive to append the jQuery object to a DOM element:

```
app.directive("jqueryToHtml", function() {
    return { 
        link: postLink
    };
    function postLink(scope, elem, attrs) {
        scope.$watch(attrs.jquery, function(value) {
            if (value) {
                elem.empty();
                elem.append(value);
            };
        }); 
    }
});
```

### Usage

```
<jquery-to-html jquery="to.testText">
</jquery-to-html>
```